# Display Admob Banner without using Storyboard or xib

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

I am new in iOS development. My app do not using storyboard and I cannot follow the [Admob iOS quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start). My app has UIViewController. Here is my code. I added `GADBannerView alloc`. However, the ads is not showing in simulator. I am using the latest SDK 7.0.0.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                             GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
// Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
// an ad request is made. GADBannerView automatically returns test ads when running on a
// simulator.
request.testDevices = @[
                        @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"  // Eric's iPod Touch
                        ];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each view you should determine superview.
In your situation this means that you should add GADBannerView to your view.

Google recommends to do it in delegate method.

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView { 
     [self.view addSubview:adView]; 
}
```

Also you can read this article - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/ad-events